# How to set the argument "url" in xmlhttp.open() when I want to use Ajax to send/receive request with node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

**server.js** can produce random number. So now I want to get a **random number** from the server and use **xmlhttp** to send a request. But the value of string is not changed when I load http://localhost:3000/index.html. What happen?

**index.js** is shown as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getRandomNum();
});

function getRandomNum() {
    $(".button").each(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        that.click(function() {
            var span = $("<span></span>").addClass("unread");
            that.append(span);
            span.text("...");
            server(span);
        });
    });
}

function server(span) {
    var string;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        string = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    span.text(string);
}
```

**server.js** is shown as follows:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var port = 3000;

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
   var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
   var mimeType = getMimeType(pathname);
   if (!!mimeType) {
       handlePage(req, res, pathname);
   } else {
       handleAjax(req, res);
   }
}).listen(port, function(){
   console.log('server listen on ', port);
});

function getMimeType(pathname) {
   var validExtensions = {
    ".html" : "text/html",
    ".js": "application/javascript",
    ".css": "text/css",
    ".jpg": "image/jpeg",
    ".gif": "image/gif",
    ".png": "image/png"
  };
  var ext = path.extname(pathname);
  var type = validExtensions[ext];
  return type;
}

function handlePage(req, res, pathname) {
    var filePath = __dirname + pathname;
    var mimeType = getMimeType(pathname);
    if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end();
        } else {
            res.setHeader("Content-Length", data.length);
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", mimeType);
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.end(data);
        }
      });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(500);
    res.end();
  }
}

function handleAjax(req, res) {
    var random_time = 1000 + getRandomNumber(2000);
    var random_num  = 1 + getRandomNumber(9);
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end("" + random_num);
    }, random_time);
}

function getRandomNumber(limit) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * limit);
}
```

Comment: What error/message do you see in your browser console when ajax returns response?

Comment: And you should update the text only after you have received response from server. You might put that update statement inside the if block that checks for request status. I would prefer jQuery's ajax method for this.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I think the problem exists due to the url and I want to know what the correct url is when I load http://localhost:3000/index.html

Comment: @NicholasLiao Please find my answer below.

Comment: @Aruna The running result is that (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) is false, which means the webpage do not repond and send the data to index.js. I think the problem is in url. You can write a simple index.html to have a try.

Comment: @NicholasLiao okay, I am creating a sample app now.

Comment: @NicholasLiao I have created a s ample app and tested this. No errors occured in your `server.js` file. You missed to handle the response in `onreadystatechange` handler in your `index.js` file. I have updated the working code below. Please give a try.

Comment: @Aruna It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `server(span)` method, you initialize sending the request and immediately assigning the null string to the span by `span.text(string)` after this line `xmlhttp.send();`.

Once the response (random number) is received from the server, you are assigning the same to the variable `string = xmlhttp.responseText;` but not updating the same to the `span`.

Also, you haven't handled the response inside the `onreadystatechange` method.

I have modified your code below. I have created a test app and tested the same. Its working as you expected.

```
function server(span) {
            var string;
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    string = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    span.text(string);
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```